# Get variable from PHP Session array with Curly Braces

Tags: php, json, session

I have this command line:

```
echo $_SESSION['info'];
```

It outputs this exact array with curly braces included:

```
{"_var1":"User","_var2":"Password"}
```

How to get the information from these variables?
To output 'User' I've tried:

```
echo $_SESSION['info']['_var1'];
```

but doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 3):

That's JSON. To get those values you need to use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$info = json_decode($_SESSION['info'], true);
echo $info['_var1'];  // User
```

The above example gives you an array since your question was using them. But you can also get back an object:

```
$info = json_decode($_SESSION['info']);
echo $info->_var1;  // User
```